# What do the different apostle skills (Evangelise belief, Launch inquisition, Spread religion) do in Civ 6, and how can I heal them?

Tags: civilization-6

I'm a little confused as to what the new apostle actions do.  The ones I currently see are:

- Evangelise belief
- Launch inquisition
- Spread religion

I'm also wondering how you heal an apostle?

Comment: Why is there no tooltip for the actions!?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Their actions in order:

- **Evangelize Belief** - This allows you to add in extra Tenets to your Religion (on top of your Pantheon and Religion bonuses)
- **Launch Inquisition** - Allows Inquisitors to be recruited, which can remove the presence of other religions.
- **Spread Religion** - Like Missionaries, Apostles can spread religion. They have a chance for promotions that make them better at it, however.

Apostles (or either of the other two religious units) can only recover HP on (or adjacent to) Holy Sites of *their Religion*.
Move the unit onto, or next to, a Holy Site and sleep / skip turn until they're back to full health.

Comment: It's also worth noting that Evangelize and Inquisition both consume the apostle - but only require 2 spread charges to work.

Comment: I've also just learnt that apostle's can be healed by them not using a turn on, or adjacent to holy sites.  http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/289076/how-to-heal-religious-units

Comment: Evangelize Belief and Launch Inquisition both require 3 charges now.

Comment: You can heal Apostle by using a Guru.