# How to heal religious units?

Tags: civilization-6

My inquisitor survived an attack from another religious unit.

How can I heal this unit?

There is no healing option. Resting the unit within my borders did not work. Resting in a city did not work either. Even a city with a holy district.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can heal religious units by sleeping them in or adjacent to Holy Districts in your own civilization. Just as any unit it cannot have used a movement/action point in order to regain health.

Promoting the unit does not heal the unit either.

I have a holy district on the border with another civ. My unit healed while standing in their territory.

In all cases, the unit being on the holy district or adjacent, the healing amount is the same.

Comment: This answer would be better with a lot more detail.  What does "sitting" mean?  Does it require a whole turn skipped in a holy district?  How much does it heal?  Does it matter if the holy district is in a city of the same religion or not?

Comment: @joe thanks for the feedback and true enough. i have updated the answer.

Comment: Updated the answer as tried and successfully healed by also standing adjacent to a holy site. Not helped by mountains I must say!

Answer (score 2):

Put your religious unit ON or next to your OWN holy district.
A rest/repair option will appear for the unit and can be clicked if you have movement points.

The healing will be done AFTER your turn like in fortify untill healed.
I tried healing ON or NEXT to a holy district from enemies and allies following MY religion (after conversion) and this doesnt seem to work.

Thats a real shame because now you have to either walk a long way back or bring lots of gurus to heal your religious units when invading foreign lands purely for theological combat and conversion.